# Java for loop won't run...?

Tags: java

I am working on a homework assignment, and the crucial loop of the program is giving me trouble. My teacher has informed me that she will take off points if I use a while loop for a counter-controlled variable, so I'm anxious to get this right.

Here's what I would like to work, and what I feel in my heart should work:

```
for ( int check = 0; check == value; check++ ) {
    int octal = getOctal();
    int decimal = convertOctal( octal );
    System.out.printf( "%d:%d", octal, decimal );
}
```

However, this loop does not run. I tried doing it with a while loop, and it worked perfectly!

```
int check = 0;
while ( check < value )
{
    int octal = getOctal();
    int decimal = convertOctal( octal );
    System.out.printf( "%d:%d", octal, decimal );
    check++;
}
```

Here is the rest of the main method:

```
public static void main ( String args[] )
{
    int value = getCount();

    while ( value < 0 )
    {
        System.out.print( "\nYou must enter a positive number" );
        value = getCount();
    }

    if ( value == 0 )
    {
        System.out.print( "\n\nNo numbers to convert.\n\n" );
    }
    else
    {   
        int check = 0;
        while ( check < value )
        {
            int octal = getOctal();
            int decimal = convertOctal( octal );
            System.out.printf( "%d:%d", octal, decimal );
            check++;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, this is an octal-to-decimal converter. I wrote the converter method myself from scratch and am ridiculously proud of it.

EDIT: MY QUESTION is, what's wrong here? 
EDIT part deux: Thanks all for your help in clearing up my misunderstanding. Onward to method documentation!

Comment: Your `while` and `for` loops are checking different conditions. The for loop is declared like this `for ( <initialization> ; <condition in order to continue> ; <actions to take after each iteration>)`

Comment: Thanks. I don't use for loops in java much, so I was misled by the wording of the expressions. ( I miss Python :( )

Comment: No prob. Go ahead and accept an answer if you think it helped/explained well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for ( int check = 0; check == value; check++ )
```

This will only run if `check == value`. Modify to:

```
for ( int check = 0; check < value; check++ )
```

Comment: oh thanks. But I don't understand... the middle thing is the termination expression, right? Not a condition to run the loop?

Comment: Termination meaning that when it goes false, the loop will stop.

Comment: nvm... as you can tell I don't use for loops in Java much

Comment: I prefer referring to it as a "condition for the loop iterate". But this syntax is the same other languages, such as C.

Answer (score 3):

try `for ( int check = 0; check <= value; check++ )` instead of `for ( int check = 0; check == value; check++ )`

Comment: sorry i was too lazy to write an explanation. see the answer of @Jean Waghetti for why it works

Answer (score 1):

From [the Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) (my emphasis):

> The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of
>   values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the
>   way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is
>   satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as
>   follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
statement(s) 
}
```

> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed
>   once, as the loop begins.
>
> **When the termination expression evaluates to
>   false, the loop terminates.**
>
> The increment expression is invoked after
>   each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this
>   expression to increment or decrement a value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same effect as:

```
int check = 0;
while (check < value) {
  // something
}
```

your `for` should look like this:

```
for (int check = 0; check < value; check++) {
  // something
}
```